# How to show only one password bullet in an input field?

Tags: javascript, html, css, validation, input

Here is a simple input field

```
<input type="password">
```

During data input, each character is displayed in bullets (# of characters = # of bullets).

```
// "password" = ********
```

How can I only display ONE bullet despite typing more characters? By using clean JS or/and CSS.

```
// "password" = *
```

Comment: Why would you do that? How doe the user know they haven't fat-fingered the password, or if their keystrokes are even registering?

Comment: **I strongly urge you not to do this.** If the "client" or your "boss" is pushing you to do it, push back if possible (point them at these comments, for instance). It's a bad idea creating a horrible user experience. It's also a pain to implement and doing so will likely causes bugs, both accessibility bugs and other kinds of bugs.

Answer (score 2):

You could just add a padding at the end of your input element to hide all but one `*`:

```css
input {
  width: 50px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<input type="password" value="Correct horse battery staple" />
```

Why you would do this is beyond me, but it works.

Actually, running this immediately shows me the first problem with this idea: My password manager's button on the input field is large enough to completely cover that first character.